# Prove $\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Prove $\frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$

I was wondering regarding this question as an alternate way to prove by first  assuming it's continuous, then using the Mean Value Theroem method:

***show that the derivative $\frac{-1}{x^2} \in [-1,0]\leq [0,\infty)$ ... ***

would a contradiction naturally arise from this? I do not know that's why I am asking.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: How are you defining $\frac{1}{x}$ at $0$?

Comment: I think you mean $(0,+\infty) $.

Comment: do you know the definition of continuity and uniform continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take $\;x_n=\frac {1}{n} $ and

$y_n=\frac {1}{n+1} .$

we have

$$x_n,y_n\in (0,+\infty) ,$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(y_n-x_n)=0$$
but
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(f (y_n)-f (x_n))=1\neq 0$$
thus $f $ is not uniformly continuous at $(0,+\infty) $.

Comment: Can you please help me understand how you got $lim_{n \to \infty}(f(y_n)-f(x_n))=1$

Comment: $f (y_n)=1/y_n=n+1$  ,$f (x_n)=n $.

Comment: So when $n \to \infty$ shouldn't $f(y_n)=f(x_n)=\infty$

Comment: @ItiShree but $f (y_n)-f (x_n)=(n+1)-n=1$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clearing up, I'm half asleep right now xD

Comment: Already gave you +1 :D